# match exact the same words between 2 strings

Tags: java

I would like to compare and match exactly one word (characters and length) between two strings.

This is what I have:

```
String wordCompare = "eagle:1,3:7;6\nBasils,45673:ewwsk\nlola:flower:1:2:b";
String lolo = scanner.nextLine();

if ( motCompare.toLowerCase().indexOf(lolo.toLowerCase()) != -1 ) {

        System.out.println("Bingo !!!");

    } else {

        System.out.println("not found !!!");

    }
```

If I type `eagle:1,3:7;6` it should display `Bingo !!!`

If I type `eagle:1,3` it still displays `Bingo !!!` which is wrong, it should display `Not found`.

If I type `eagle:1,3:7;6 Basils,45673:ewwsk` or `eagle:1,3:7;6\nBasils,45673:ewwsk` it should also display `Not Found`. Length of the typed word should be acknowledged between `\n`.

If I type `Basils,45673:ewwsk`, it displays `bingo !!!`

Comment: Fix punctuation.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like what you're wanting is an exact match, with the words being split by the newline character. With that assumption in mind, I would recommend splitting the string out into an array and then loading that into a HashSet like so:

```
boolean search(String wordDictionary, String search){
    String[] options = wordDictionary.split("\n"); 
    HashSet<String> searchSet = new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(options));
    return searchSet.contains(search);
}
```

If the search function returns true, it has found whatever word you're searching for, if not, it hasn't.
Installing it in your code will look something like this:

```
String wordCompare = "eagle:1,3:7;6\nBasils,45673:ewwsk\nlola:flower:1:2:b";
String lolo = scanner.nextLine();
if(search(wordCompare, lolo))
    System.out.println("Bingo!!!");
else
    System.out.println("Not found.");
```

(For the record, you'd probably be better off with more clear variable names)

Comment: I cannot use Tables [] nor expressions such as new HashSet<String>(Arrays.asList(options)) and search(wordCompare, lolo)

Comment: Why can't you use arrays or HashSets? You can't use methods? And there's no regex used here.

Comment: I can not use them because these are the restrictions of the homework.

Comment: In that case I would use `indexOf(String s)`. This method will return the index of `s` within whatever string you're using it on. So, `int index = wordCompare.indexOf(lolo)`. Then, `wordCompare.substring(index+s.length(), index+s.length()+2).equals("\n")` will return true if that substring is followed by `\n`, which is what you want. Now, you may need to add stuff for the edge case of `s.length()+2` being greater than `wordCompare.length()`, but on the whole this should be what you're going for. This also relies on `\n` being only used as a divider and not a potential searchable substring.

Comment: Thank you. I would like know to if "String s" you mentioned  refers to lolo.

Comment: Oh, whoops. Yes, read that as `wordCompare.substring(index+lolo.length(), index+lolo.length()+2).equals("\n")`. My bad.

Answer (score 0):

As @Grey has already mentioned within his answer, since you have a newline tag (\n) between your phrases you can Split the String using the **String.split()** method into a String Array and then compare the elements of that Array for equality with what the User supplies.

The code below is **just another example** of how this can be done. It also allows for the option to Ignore Letter case:

```
boolean ignoreCase = false;
String userString = "Basils,45673:ewwsk";
String isInString = "'" + userString + "' Was Not Found !!!";
String wordCompare = "eagle:1,3:7;6\nBasils,45673:ewwsk\nlola:flower:1:2:b";
String[] tmp = wordCompare.split("\n");
for (int i = 0; i < tmp.length; i++) {
    // Ternary used for whether or not to ignore letter case.
    if (!ignoreCase ? tmp[i].trim().equals(userString) : 
                      tmp[i].trim().equalsIgnoreCase(userString)) {
        isInString = "Bingo !!!";
        break;
    }
}
System.out.println(isInString);
```

Comment: As mentionned, I cannot use Tables [] nor expressions such as !ignoreCase ? tmp[i].trim().equals(userString) and neither break

Answer (score 0):

Thank you,

The thing is I am not allowed to  use regular expression nor tables.

so basing on your suggestions I made this code :

```
motCompare.toLowerCase().indexOf(lolo.toLowerCase(), ' ' ) != -1 ||
    motCompare.toLowerCase().lastIndexOf(lolo.toLowerCase(),' ' ) != -1)
```

as a condition for a do while loop.

Could you please confirm if it is correct ?

Thank you.